# Add ttl field in scapy

Tags: python, dns, server, scapy, ttl

```
from scapy.all import *    
respPkt = IP(dst=pkt[IP].src)/UDP(dport=pkt[UDP].sport)/DNS()
respPkt[DNS] = response[DNS]
```

I wrote this, I want to add ttl field to the response.
how can I do It ? 
thanks for the answers! : )

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty hard to help you solve your issue with an ambiguous question and a non-working incomplete example.

setting the IP ttl field:

```
pkt[IP].ttl = 123
pkt = IP(ttl=123, ...)
```

DNS resource record ttl:

```
DNSRR(..., ttl=1234)
```